# Simulate a click on a div element with "role=button" -- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, youtube

Good day,

I know this question has been asked many times. I searched high and low to get it to work but it seems that something has changed that the answers are not working anymore.

On YouTube, when I run this simulateClick function in the console. It works.

```js
function simulateClick() {
  var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window
  });
  var cb = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-play-button")[0]; //element to click on
  var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
  if(canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}
```

That is because there is a button called "ytp-play-button".

However, when I take that to YouTube TV (formerly leanback). It does not work. The div function there has a "role=button".

This is the div responsible for the play button.

```html
<div class="toggle-button selected material-icon-play-arrow toggle-selected transport-controls-toggle-button" tabindex="-1" role="button" style="">  <div class="background"></div>  <span class="label">Pause</span></div>
```

So I changed the "ytp-play-button" to the "material-icon-play-arrow" but even though it gets the class right. It does not work.

Any pointers would be truly appreciated it. Thank you.

P.S.: This is a pure JavaScript question not a jQuery one.

Edit#1: When I tried to run the onclick like this in the console

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("material-icon-play-arrow")[0].onclick()
```

I got this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0].onclick is not a function
>       at :1:64
>   (anonymous) @ VM7969:1

Comment: Can you clarify whether you have a problem adding a onclick event to a div or something else?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I tried adding it as in "document.getElementsByClassName("material-icon-play-arrow")[0].onclick()" But still it did not work. I got an error, I believe. Would you care to clarify if I am doing it wrong, Thanks!

Comment: Amanda, please [edit] your question and add also the description error.

Comment: Done. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why aren't you using `dispatchEvent` like in the example above? And from the looks of the error, you make sure you did `document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0].onclick()`, WITH parenthesis.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey I tried the dispatchEvent and it did not work. So, I am trying to run it in the console with parenthesis but that is the error I got. I triple checked it. The parenthesis are there

Comment: it should just be `.click()`, not `.onclick()`.

Comment: When I tried that. I got "undefined". Running the simulateClick function raise the alarm but do not click the play button. (i.e., the video continues to play)

Comment: Using the dispatchEvent in the console returns "true" but again no effect on the button.

Comment: @Amanda, if I understand correctly, you want play/pause a YouTube video by clicking *(using javascript)* the button element that in YouTube plays/pauses the video. If this is true, can you why you want to do this functionality in this way? - I'm saying this because if you're using the YouTube API iframe, you can set a YouTube video and play/pause the video. See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Playback_controls

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you for all your help :).

Comment: @Amanda sure. Thank you for clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [YouTube Iframe Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en) for set a embed YouTube video and control the way you can interact with the video.

For your specific case, you need play/pause a YouTube video by clicking an HTML element *(in this case, a div element)*.

For achieve this functionality, you can use the following code - see the working sample in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/xujn3pgc/1/).

There, basically I have a div element *(called `playButton`)* and *(using the `onPlayerStateChange` function)* I set the click event as follows:

- When the video is playing, the div `playButton` will have its text as "Pause" and its click event allows pause the video.
- When the video is paused, the div `playButton` will have its text as "Play" and its click event allows play the video.

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Variables of the divs (where the YouTube iframe will load):
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  // Div player:
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '360',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });

  // After loading the iframe, set the "playVideo" onclick event on "playButton" anchor element.
  document.getElementById('playButton').onclick = function() {
    player.playVideo();
  };

}

// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

  // If the video is PLAYING, set the onclick element for pause the video.
  // Once the "playButton" is clicked, the video will be paused.
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    document.getElementById('playButton').innerHTML = 'Pause';

    // Set the onclick event to the button for pause the YouTube video.
    document.getElementById('playButton').onclick = function() {
      player.pauseVideo();
    };
  }

  // If the video is PAUSED, set the onclick element for pause the video.
  // Once the "playButton" is clicked, the video will resume the video = continue playing the video.
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
    document.getElementById('playButton').innerHTML = 'Play';
    document.getElementById('playButton').onclick = function() {
      player.playVideo();
    };
  }
}

// Div "player" - The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}
```

```html
<!-- In this div, the YouTube video will be loaded with YouTube iframe Player API. -->
<div id="player"></div>

<!-- N.B this is the div element used for play or pause the current video loaded with YouTube iframe Player API. -->
<a href="#" id="playButton">Play</a>
```

Here is the "[Playback controls and player settings](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Playback_controls)" in the official documentation for further details.